# Prove the maps are homotopic equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $\alpha : P \rightarrow Q, \beta : Q \rightarrow R$ and $\gamma : R \rightarrow S$ be morphisms of $R$-module complexes($R$ is a commutative ring). When $\beta\alpha$ and $\gamma\beta$
are homotopy equivalences, prove that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\gamma\beta\alpha$ are also homotopy equivalence.

My attempt:

Let $f$ be the homotopy inverse of $\beta\alpha$ and $g$ be the homotopy inverse of $\gamma\beta$. therefore we have: $f\beta\alpha\sim Id^{P}$ and $\beta\alpha f\sim Id^{R}$. Similarly, $\gamma\beta g\sim Id^{S}$ and $g\gamma\beta\sim Id^{Q}$. Therefroe, my guess for the homotopy inverse of $\alpha$ is $f\beta$ and it follows that $f\beta\alpha\sim Id^{P}$, but I don't understand how to show $\alpha f\beta\sim Id^{B}$, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, in any category, if $\beta\alpha$ and $\gamma\beta$ are isomorphisms, then so are $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ and $\gamma\beta\alpha$.  The trick for showing this is the fact that if a morphism $f$ has both a left inverse $g$ and a right inverse $h$ then they are equal so the morphism is an isomorphism.  To prove this, just consider the composition $gfh$ which is equal to both $(gf)h=h$ and $g(fh)=g$.

In particular, since $\beta\alpha$ is an isomorphism, $\beta$ has a right inverse (if $f$ is the inverse of $\beta\alpha$ then $\alpha f$ is a right inverse to $\beta$) and since $\gamma\beta$ is an isomorphism, $\beta$ has a left inverse.  Thus $\beta$ is an isomorphism, and now it follows that everything else is an isomorphism too (as a composition of isomorphisms).